# ApolloProvider useMutation Promise Resolution Causing React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, gql, mutation

In an async await call on a button onClick with ApolloProvider context:

```
await showDialog(renderProps => (
                                    <ApolloProvider>
...
                                    </ApolloProvider>
                                ));
```

I need to execute a GQL mutation via useMutation:

```
const [promiseObj, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation(MUTATION);

promiseObj().then(result => {
    console.log(result.data);
    return (<React.Fragment>UI element</React.Fragment>)
});
```

In the console I see the result data logged infinitely.

What I need is to return a dialog as a UI element when the promise resolves but that doesn't happen due to infinite calls to renderWithHooks.

It looks like this infinite loop is caused by React re-rendering the components, but it never ends. How can I stop this from happening?

The error is:

```
library.js:1310101 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
at renderWithHooks (library.js:1310101:17)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (library.js:1312915:13)
at beginWork (library.js:1314153:16)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (library.js:1299049:14)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (library.js:1299098:16)
at invokeGuardedCallback (library.js:1299160:31)
at beginWork$1 (library.js:1319063:7)
at performUnitOfWork (library.js:1317878:12)
at workLoopSync (library.js:1317806:5)
at renderRootSync (library.js:1317769:7)
```

Comment: can you provide the whole component structure? It's hard for us to tell where the problem is coming from with that code sample. If we based on your sample, your promiseObj seems to be called during component render and not on any hooks or function.